# Get all frames from loaded swf in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, movieclip, displayobject

I load external SWF with help `MovieClipSWFLoader` and add them to scene with `addElement`. So I know about frames total count and can navigate using nextFrame/prevFrame. I need to create panel with thumbnails which contains preview for each frame. How I can get each frame from MovieClip and store in array for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a BitmapData object for each preview. Just iterate through each frame in your MC and use myBitmapData.draw(mc). Then create bitmaps: new Bitmap(myBitmapData); from each BitmapData and put them into your panel.

Comment: Thank you! I iterate MovieClip frames and do bitmap for each frame and it works perfectly!